# Scroll Bars For Multiple JTextPanes (Java)

Tags: java, scroll, jframe, jscrollpane, jtextpane

Attached is my window code:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
public class Window extends JFrame{
    private JPanel panel;
    private JTextPane textPane;
    private JTextPane textPane_1;   
    public Window() {
        super("Window");
        this.init();
        this.setSize(800, 600);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
    void init(){
        panel = new JPanel();
        getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panel.setLayout(null);      
        textPane = new JTextPane();
        textPane.setBounds(6, 48, 788, 185);
        panel.add(textPane);
        textPane.setFocusable(true);        
        textPane_1 = new JTextPane();
        textPane_1.setBounds(6, 346, 788, 185);
        panel.add(textPane_1);      
        JScrollPane scroll1 = new JScrollPane(textPane, ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        scroll1.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        scroll1.setViewportView(textPane);
        panel.add(scroll1);
        this.add(scroll1);      
        JScrollPane scroll2 = new JScrollPane(textPane_1, ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        scroll2.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        scroll2.setViewportView(textPane);
        panel.add(scroll2);
        this.add(scroll2);      
        this.add(panel);
    }
}
```

My objective is for both JTextPanes to have their own scroll bars.  All that appears on the screen though is a single JTextPane (not sure which one), and it has only a vertical scroll bar (I think this is because JTextPanes have word wrap).  The second JTextPane isn't showing up.  Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance to all who reply.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `GridLayout` in this case. See *Swing Tutorial* on [How to Use GridLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html)

Here is the code with `GridLayout` along with inline comments.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class MyWindow extends JFrame {
    private JPanel panel;
    private JTextPane textPane;
    private JTextPane textPane_1;

    public MyWindow() {
        super("Window");
        this.init();
    }

    void init() {
        // panel with GridLayout having 2 rows and 1 column
        panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,1)); 

        textPane = new JTextPane();
        // enclose the text pane inside the scroll pane
        // scroll pane shows scrollbars when needed
        JScrollPane scroll1 = new JScrollPane(textPane);
        // add scroll pane at first column of the first row
        // never add text pane again in the panel because 
        //  it's already added in scroll pane
        panel.add(scroll1);

        textPane_1 = new JTextPane();
        JScrollPane scroll2 = new JScrollPane(textPane_1);
        // add scroll pane  at first column of the second row
        panel.add(scroll2);

        // finally add the panel in the JFrame's content pane in the center
        getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){

            @Override
            public void run() {
                MyWindow window=new MyWindow();
                window.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

snapshot:

[image]

---

Please have a look at *Swing Tutorial* on [How to Use Various Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/layoutlist.html)

Comment: so what should I do about the scroll bars on my JTextPanes?

Comment: A few points, unless it's directly related to solving the problem. I would out your tips last, focus on solving the problem first, as I read about half it and thought, how is this an answer, in fact, only the last line is even close to solving the problem at hand. It's not that the tips aren't useful, but they are distracting people from the answer and puts your answer at the borderline of not been an answer, just saying ;)

Comment: sorry.  i don't understand what your comment means.

Comment: @user3870884 Wasn't directed at you sorry ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer I am Sorry, I apologize for this. I should focus on the problem first. I know still my post never suggest the issues that you have already answered.

Comment: @user3218114 You're points were valid, just needed to be last, unless they directly impacted the answer, such as you comments about `BorderLayout` and `null` layouts for example.  The use of `GridLayout` is a good suggestion ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer I am extremely sorry. Thanks again for your guideline.

Answer (score 1):

Two points to start with, first, `JFrame` uses a `BorderLayout` by default, a `BorderLayout` only allows a single component to occupy any one of its five available positions.  Second a component can only belong to a single parent

Taking a look at your code...

```
    scroll1.setViewportView(textPane);
    panel.add(scroll1);
    this.add(scroll1);      
    //...
    scroll2.setViewportView(textPane);
    panel.add(scroll2);
    this.add(scroll2);      
    this.add(panel);
```

1. You set `textPane` as the viewport view for `scroll1`
2. You add `scroll1` to `panel`
3. You add `scroll` to `this`, effectively removing it from `panel`...
4. You set `textPane` as the viewport view of `scroll2`, removing it from the viewport for `scroll1`
5. You add `scroll2` to the `panel`
6. You add `scroll2` to this, effectively removing it from `panel`...
7. You add `panel` to this, overriding everything that was added to the frame previously...

This effectively means that `panel` is the only visible component the `BorderLayout` will try to layout on the frame, but it contains nothing

Instead, you could specify a position for each scroll pane when adding it to the frame, for example..

```
    scroll1.setViewportView(textPane);
    this.add(scroll1, BorderLayout.NORTH);      
    //...
    scroll2.setViewportView(textPane_1);
    this.add(scroll2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

**Updated with working example**

[image: Does Work]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Window extends JFrame {

    private JTextPane textPane;
    private JTextPane textPane_1;

    public Window() {
        super("Window");
        this.init();
        this.setSize(800, 600);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    void init() {
        textPane = new JTextPane();
        textPane_1 = new JTextPane();
        JScrollPane scroll1 = new JScrollPane(textPane);
        scroll1.setViewportView(textPane);
        JScrollPane scroll2 = new JScrollPane(textPane_1);
        add(scroll1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(scroll2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                Window frame = new Window();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This is the default behaviour for a `JTextPane`, it's overall size is determine by the size of it's content...

Now, you can make suggestions to the scrollpane about how much space your component would like to use by using the `Scrollable` interface and specifying the "initial", `PreferredScrollableViewportSize`...

Lucky for you, `JTextPane` already implements this interface, so you only need to override the `getPreferredScrollableViewportSize` method, for example...

[image: Does Work]

```
textPane = new JTextPane() {
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredScrollableViewportSize() {
        return new Dimension(200, 200);
    }
};
textPane_1 = new JTextPane() {
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredScrollableViewportSize() {
        return new Dimension(200, 200);
    }
};
```

Take a look at [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for more details

Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

Comment: that doesn't work.  it only shows the textPane_1 on the bottom of the screen.  It is extremely tiny, and the textPane that should be on the north isn't there.

Comment: It does work, if you are 100% sure you're not adding the text pane of scroll pane to something else...